# Import from Excel and Export to new Excel sheet C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, export-to-excel

Hi i have a 20 data in an Excel sheet. i want to read the excel sheet and export the first 10 data to new excel sheet and last 10 data to another new excel sheet. kindly tell me the logic

Comment: @mwisnicki that edit should not have been approved. Don't use `inline code` to highlight random terms.

Comment: You can read from excel sheet and insert data rows to datatable and then write first 10 rows to one excel sheet and next 10 rows to another. You can easily put effort in knowing how to create and read from excel sheets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@selva.. you could read the data from excel sheet and hold it in a data table .
You can manipulate the data table as per you need and export the content to excel sheets again.
In your case you could export the 1st 10 rows and last 10 rows to seperate sheets respectively